# My Audit Trail Script Isn't Working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using the below code to audit my forms for changes. It works perfectly when I use "MBRID" which is the ID field on tbl_MBR. However, when I use "IMID" which is the ID field on tbl_ItemMaster, I get an error: can't find the field 'IMID' referred to in your expression. Any idea why IMID cannot be found?

```
Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
If Status = acDeleteOK Then Call AuditChanges("IMID", "DELETE")
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.NewRecord Then
    Call AuditChanges("IMID", "NEW")
Else
    Call AuditChanges("IMID", "EDIT")
End If
End Sub

Sub AuditChanges(IDField As String, UserAction As String)
On Error GoTo AuditChanges_Err
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ctl As Control
Dim datTimeCheck As Date
Dim strUserID As String
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tbl_AuditChanges", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
datTimeCheck = Now()
strUserID = Environ("USERNAME")
Select Case UserAction
    Case "EDIT"
        For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Debug.Print ctl.Name
            If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                        ![UserName] = strUserID
                        ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                        ![Action] = UserAction
                        ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                        ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                        ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                        ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                        .Update
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next ctl
    Case Else
        With rst
            .AddNew
            ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
            ![UserName] = strUserID
            ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
            ![Action] = UserAction
            ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
            .Update
        End With
End Select
AuditChanges_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
AuditChanges_Err:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!"
Resume AuditChanges_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? Disable the error handler for debugging. Or set a breakpoint on first line of code and step execute. Code is looking for a control named IMID. Is there one? Controls do not have to be named same as fields they are bound to.

Comment: It doesn't give me that info. When I try to compile it, no error is thrown. I tried going line by line and the error comes when looking for IMID. When I use MBRiD (the ID field for tbl_MBR) all ctls work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a little hidden but I found it. The field IMID wasn't in the query associated with the subform. Therefore, when the code looked for "IMID" it was not found.

Adding "IMID" to the query solved the problem.